# Apache Shiro Guice Servlet Configure redirectUrl for AUTHC Filter

Tags: servlets, guice, servlet-filters, shiro, guice-servlet

How can I configure the redirect URL for the AUTHC Filter given by Shiro? I know how to configure it in an INI file, but I need to know how to configure it in my extension of the ShiroWebModule.
Thanks!

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before adding the tag. This is the 2nd time you used `[filter]` instead of `[servlet-filters]` while the tag description of `[filter]` clearly tells that you should be using `[servlet-filters]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the doc [here](http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html#Guice-Properties) , I would start by trying something like this:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.successUrl")).to("/myHomePage.jsp");
```

Comment: Ok! Works for me! Thanks! Is there any documentation about the parameter names in Guice?